# Canvas parameters being sent from Aura component intermittently

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, canvas, canvas-app

We have a Canvas App embedded in tab in a lightning page. The tab only consists of the Aura component which has the Canvas implemented.

Aura Comp:

```
<aura:component controller="TradeExperienceUICanvasController" description="TradeExperienceUICanvas" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="item" type="String" access="global" />
   <aura:attribute name="canvasParameters" type="string" />
   <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <force:canvasApp height="600px" width="100%" developerName="Trade_Experience_Admin_UI" parameters="{!v.canvasParameters}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Controller and helper:

```
    ({
        doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
            helper.getAccountInfo(cmp);
        }
    })

({
    getAccountInfo: function(cmp) {
        var recordId = cmp.get("v.recordId");
        var action = cmp.get("c.getAccount");
        var item = cmp.get("v.item");

            action.setParams({ "accountId" : recordId });
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                    var result = response.getReturnValue();
                    cmp.set("v.account", result);
                    cmp.set("v.canvasParameters", JSON.stringify({
                        Object: 'company',
                        Id: result.Company_ID__c,
                        Item: item
                    }));
    
                    console.log('Params being sent to auth app: '+cmp.get("v.canvasParameters"));
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    })
```

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class TradeExperienceUICanvasController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount(Id accountId){
        Account acc = [SELECT Id, Company_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: accountId];
        return acc;
    }
}
```

It does pass the parameters sometimes (first screenshot) and at times it doesn't (second screen shot)

[image]

[image]

The **parameters are not being set at times i.e. null** and at times they are being set? Can someone please let us know where the problem could be as this seems to be a simple enough Aura component with no complex logic involved? We've tried to reach out to Salesforce support but that didn't help